# What is error no such table: ... in android?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-logcat

[image]I need to show my data on a `ListView` everything is correct but When i run this project i get this `error` :

```
(1) no such table: WebSite_CategoryBack
```

My `DataBase` is correct .I think that my code has error.

This is my `MainActivity.java`:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {   
public static Context context;
public static final String DIR_SDCARD =Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
public static final String DIR_DATABASE = DIR_SDCARD + "/Mafatih/";
DB db = new DB(MainActivity.this);
public String Titel_Drawer;
public String messageCursor;
private ListView mainListView ;
public SQLiteDatabase  sql;
public Cursor cursor;
public ArrayList<String> array;
private ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        File file= new File(DIR_DATABASE);
        file.mkdirs();
        try{
            db.createDataBase();
          }catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("create DB3", e.toString());
        }
        try{
            db.openDataBase();
           }catch (SQLException e) {
                Log.e("create DB3", e.toString());
            }
        sql = db.getReadableDatabase();
        cursor = sql.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM WebSite_CategoryBack;", null);
        array = new ArrayList<String>();
        while(cursor.moveToNext()){
            Titel_Drawer = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("tittle"));
            array.add(Titel_Drawer);
        }
        cursor.close();
        mainListView = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.mainListView );
        listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.drawer_layout_main,R.id.rowTextView_Main, array);
        mainListView.setAdapter( listAdapter );
         mainListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
             @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,long arg3) {
                int itemposition = position;
                String itemvalue = (String) mainListView.getItemAtPosition(position);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Position :"+itemposition+"  ListItem : " +itemvalue , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
         mainListView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    }
```

And this is my `DB.java`:

```
public class DB extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    public static final String DIR_SDCARD =Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    public static final String DIR_DATABASE = DIR_SDCARD + "/Mafatih/";

    private static  String DB_NAME = "Resaleh.db";

    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;

    private final Context myContext;

    /**
* Constructor
* Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to access to the application assets and resources.
* @param context
*/
    public DB(Context context) {

     super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
        this.myContext = context;
    }   

  /**
* Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own database.
* */
    public void createDataBase() throws IOException{

     boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

     if(dbExist){
     //do nothing - database already exist
     }else{

     //By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
     //of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
         this.getReadableDatabase();

             try {
                    copyDataBase();

             } catch (IOException e) {

                    throw new Error("Error copying database --> "+e.toString());

         }
     }

    }

    /**
* Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
* @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
*/
    private boolean checkDataBase(){

     SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

     try{
     String myPath = DIR_DATABASE + DB_NAME;
     checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
     }catch(SQLiteException e){
         Log.e("asdf", "checkDataBase-->"+e.toString());
     }

     if(checkDB != null){

     checkDB.close();

     }

     return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
* @see android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper#getReadableDatabase()
*/
@Override
public synchronized SQLiteDatabase getReadableDatabase() {
return super.getReadableDatabase();
}


/**
* Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
* system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
* This is done by transfering bytestream.
* */
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

     //Open your local db as the input stream
     InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

     // Path to the just created empty db
     String outFileName = DIR_DATABASE + DB_NAME;

     //Open the empty db as the output stream
     OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

     //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
     byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
     int length;
     try{
     while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
     myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
     }
     }catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Copy", e.toString());
    }

     //Close the streams
     myOutput.flush();
     myOutput.close();
     myInput.close();

    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{

     //Open the database
        String myPath = DIR_DATABASE + DB_NAME;
     myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY|SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);

    }

    @Override
public synchronized void close() {

     if(myDataBase != null)
     myDataBase.close();

     super.close();

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}
}
```

THANKS.

Comment: it means that the database does not contain the table you mentioned in the `from` clause

Comment: I saw my database but i have this table.

Comment: The evidence shows that you database does not contain this table.

Comment: You can see photo of database.

Comment: Has the phone got the same db file on the SD Card? The screenshot shows a db file on C:\Users...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the SQLite DB is created and saved in the path : data/data/.... on internal storage and opened from there. In case we want to save it on SD card, the address should be manually set and called exactly from the SD card otherwise we will have error.
The correct code is:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

public static Context context;
public static final String DIR_SDCARD =Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
public static final String DIR_DATABASE = DIR_SDCARD + "/Mafatih/";
public String Titel_Drawer;
public String messageCursor;
private ListView mainListView ;
public SQLiteDatabase  sql;
public Cursor cursor;
public ArrayList<String> array;
private ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter ;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        File file= new File(DIR_DATABASE);
        file.mkdirs();
        sql = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(DIR_DATABASE + "/Resaleh.db", null);
        cursor = sql.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM WebSite_CategoryBack;", null);
        array = new ArrayList<String>();
        while(cursor.moveToNext()){
            Titel_Drawer = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("tittle"));
            array.add(Titel_Drawer);
        }
        cursor.close();
        mainListView = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.mainListView );
        listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.drawer_layout_main,R.id.rowTextView_Main, array);
        mainListView.setAdapter( listAdapter );
         mainListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
             @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,long arg3) {
                int itemposition = position;
                String itemvalue = (String) mainListView.getItemAtPosition(position);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Position :"+itemposition+"  ListItem : " +itemvalue , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
         mainListView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    }
```

Delete the DB.java.THANKS.

Answer (score 0):

There is one good reason why this error will come and i used to get this...

The reason why i got was like i created the db without THAT TABLE now when during course of time if i add a new table then it wont appear and i used to get the error so to make it fresh i used to do the following :-

1. rename DB.
2. change version of DB.
3. uninstall the app.
4. now install the app.

This used to solve the issue in my case...

thx

Comment: You can see photo of database.

Comment: is it the first query ? i mean when u run the app is this one is the first place where db is used? or you able to run any query before the place where crash is coming ?